# How to only get the initial touch for a "jump" command for an Android game in Unity

Tags: c#, android, mobile, unity-game-engine

I have this code to make the spaceship go up and not let gravity crush it against the floor.

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * force);
```

But when I go play the game on my phone, the game is tracking whether or not I **keep pressing/touching** the screen, and increasing the force with which I go up according to it. This makes it really difficult because it is very sensitive, I need to really focus and tap **really** fast to not make it go *puf* up the sky (and against the roof which is another obstacle in my game).

Also, if any of you can give me some pointers on how to make the GUI scale according to device screen I'd REALLY appreciate it, I can't seem to figure it out even with a couple of tutorials, I feel stupid.

Comment: Is that code in your `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()`?  Rigid bodies should use the latter.  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

Comment: @MickyDuncan You're right, I had that wrong. Still, the ship is fine with a force of "300" when playing on desktop, but for some reason that I'm sure it's obvious to someone experienced, when going to mobile I have to use a force of "20" to make it playable. Is there not a way to make the game stop registering the touch after I do it once?

Comment: Goodo. I'd say once you work out the GUI scaling the forces may fall into place.  e.g. it doesn't make immediate sense to me to change gravity just because the screen size is say 640x480 instead of 1080p.  Then again I may be wrong.  Velocities generally are expressed in pixels/second.  Perhaps your max velocity should be a function of screen resolution?  I wish you well

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean variable to make sure that the force is applied only once per touch.

```
private bool touchCont = false;
void Update(){
    if (!touchCont && Input.touchCount > 0){
        touchCont = true;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * force);
    }

    if (Input.touchCount == 0){
        touchCont = false;
    }
}
```

Even though `FixedUpdate()` is usually recommended for rigidbodies, my algorithm is using `Update()`, because touch events are changing for every update. This way and with the help of the boolean variable the force is only add once per new beginning of touch events.

Or if you want to apply the force on every new touch, even they are concurrent, you can use `Input.touches` to get all the touches. If any of the touches are `TouchPhase.Began`, it means they have just started.

If you are setting your GUI sizes in code, one way to make GUI scale is that you can use for example `Screen.width / 8` instead of `200`. For better scaling, even the font size can be set the same way.

Comment: OP stated _"the game is tracking whether or not I keep pressing/touching the screen"_.  Your code will have the net effect of the OP's code of `if (Input.touchCount > 0)` I would think.  Also this goes against Unity's guidelines of _[FixedUpdate should be used instead of Update when dealing with Rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)_

Comment: My code is better to use `Update`, since `Touch` events are updated on very update not every fixedUpdate. ["its suggested you make all the Input Calls in the Update Loop."](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html) With net affect do you mean that with two touches my code would add the force twice?  It is not doing that because it is only called once every update and using the flag variable to avoid that.

Comment: @maZZZu I'll fiddle with your suggestion in a lil' bit. The GUI, I actually have it set up with screen.width/height, but the font is still really small. It's like I am scaling the position of the labels and buttons but not the font, so they are well positioned but look way too small.

Comment: You can also set the font size as a proportion of the screen size.

Comment: Ah good point about the touch events during `Update()`.  Perhaps we need to read input during `Update()`, setting  `touchCont` but perform the forces during `FixedUpdate()`.  If you make any edit to your question I'll undo the downvote

Comment: IMHO it is much better practice to keep the code simple and just set the force in the `Update()`. Your link is giving an example of constant force. In this case the force is applied only once so the action causing it to be set can simply call the one liner (likely the compiler will make so that it is actually applied in the next fixedupdate). I edited my answer correspondingly.

Comment: It's nothing to do with keeping the code simple.  Thanks for editing. +1